# Add Movable view inside MPAndroidChart on LongPress of Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Friends

I am stuck in one issue as i am new to Android.

I am using MPAndroidChart Library. And want to add movable button inside chart.

Can we add any button inside chart which can move according to touch position of chart, Button should be visible when we Long Press the chart and if we click button then dialog should appear.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using markers and highlights. Please refer following links of documentation to implement this:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/IMarker-Interface
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Highlighting